# Is it a good idea to cast rvalue argument on calling a function?

Tags: c++11

I wrote the following code and wonder if this is a good idea. Are there any technical reasons not to call foo() like this? E.g. will all destructors will be called correctly?

```
foo(std::istream&& input) { ... }

foo(std::ifstream("myfile.txt"));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use an rvalue reference and not a reference? What is foo doing with input? Making a copy?

Comment: Do you have any reasons _to_ do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Before "technical reasons" can be addressed, we need to know what semantic purpose you're trying to convey here. When I see that signature, what I see is a function that will take ownership of the stream. But since you used a base class rather than the derived class, you can't really move the stream anywhere. So your interface is semantically incoherent.

Comment: I could take an lvalue ref but that would prevent the on-the-fly construction in the second statement. But why is the interface semantically incoherent? Imho it says something like: "Give me a stream I will consume.". What is wrong with that? The interesting part is where foo() is called.

Comment: It's taking a reference, quite the opposite of consuming anything; if you want it to consume a stream, take one by value, not by reference.

Comment: @ildjarn It's an rvalue reference. So the caller transfers ownership to the callee. That's what I mean with "consume".

Comment: @Woowoo : Binding to an rvalue reference no more transfers ownership than binding to an lvalue reference copies – it's still just a reference. If you want to transfer ownership, you need an _object_ to own; hence, pass by value, and if the caller had an lvalue they were moving from they will actually find it _moved from_ (unlike with a reference).

Comment: @ildjarn But rvalue reference means: "No one else has a handle to that thing", right? In that sense I'm the only owner. Or do I miss something?

Comment: @Woowoo : It means no such thing; `std::string s; auto&& s1 = std::move(s); auto&& s2 = std::move(s);` is perfectly legal and does exactly nothing, because again, binding a reference does nothing.. An rvalue reference _can_ be used to move-construct or move-assign an object, but unless you actually do that it's just a reference like any other. So, to reiterate: if you want to transfer ownership, make the parameter a value, not a reference.

Comment: @ildjarn Thanks, that corrected my mental model. But apart from the interface not being sensible. Is there any technical problem like resource leak?

Comment: Nope, not at all; just potential confusion. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn If you would write that as an answer, i could accept it ;)